# Different certificate being presented to node.js vs the browser

Tags: node.js, ssl, https

When I access https://gmail.com in the browser I'm sent a 301 redirect to https://mail.google.com. When I try to do the same thing using node.js I get a "Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames" error.

This makes sense since the certificate offered by gmail.com to node.js doesn't include "gmail.com" as ther common name nor as an alt-name. This is the certificate being presented by gmail.com...

```
{ subject: 
   { C: 'US',
     ST: 'California',
     L: 'Mountain View',
     O: 'Google Inc',
     CN: 'mail.google.com' },
  issuer: { C: 'US', O: 'Google Inc', CN: 'Google Internet Authority G2' },
  subjectaltname: 'DNS:mail.google.com',
  exponent: '10001',
  valid_from: 'Feb 25 15:21:00 2014 GMT',
  valid_to: 'May 26 00:00:00 2014 GMT'}
```

When I check the certificate that should be presented by the server I see  http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=gmail.com which DOES include the gmail.com extension. I assume this is what the browser is recieving.

Why is node being sent a different certificate to the browser?
Could this have anything to do with CNAMEs and DNS?

Comment: It seems that the use of https.globalAgent.options.secureProtocol = 'SSLv3_method' changes whether this works or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be because your browser supports [Server Name Indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) (SNI) and Node.js (or rather, the client module you're using) does not. Since certificate negotiation happens before HTTP can begin, SNI is needed in order to serve more than one hostname from a single IP address.

Comment: The TLS module documentation (which I believe is what is in use behind the scenes) does appear to support SNI based on this http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_npn_and_sni. Still, your theory is as good as I've got at the moment.

Does my finding that the existence of the https.globalAgent.options.secureProtocol = 'SSLv3_method' flag is causing the issue change your guess at all?

Comment: If I understand your comments correctly, removing the `SSLv3_method` flag fixes it, which does make some sense. (SNI is a TLS extension, and doesn't exist in SSL as far as I know.) If your client doesn't indicate the server name during handshaking, the server has no way to know what you're looking for and presents a default certificate.

Comment: Accepting answer based on the inclusion of the above comment. Much thanks Henry.